# dot syntax to access data in a ggplot2 layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

could someone help me figure out the meaning of `.` in the `data` argument of a ggplot2 layer? Any doc or blog post where I can read about it?

```
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_text(
    aes(x=1, y=cyl, label=hp), 
    data=. %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(hp=mean(hp)) 
  )
```

Obviously this is not the usual dot introduced by magrittr's pipe since there is no pipe before the dot…

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The  +  for ggplot acts as the pipe from magrittr's package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are official docs, but we can retrace the steps ggplot2 makes to figure out what is happening. First, the piece of the piping gets stored as a function (sub)class object.

```r
library(tidyverse)

(x <- . %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(hp = mean(hp)))
#> Functional sequence with the following components:
#> 
#>  1. group_by(., cyl)
#>  2. summarise(., hp = mean(hp))
#> 
#> Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
class(x)
#> [1] "fseq"     "function"
```

Then when ggplot2 ingests the piping operation, it fortifies it as a function. You can inspect the `layer` function body to see this. In this case, it does nothing but return the function you already had. This gets stored in the layer object you get out of any `geom_*()` or `stat_*()` function you call.

```
ggplot2:::fortify.function
#> function(model, data, ...) model
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000014a1d878>
#> <environment: namespace:ggplot2>
```

Lastly, when the plot gets build, the layer checks if the data is a function, and if it is, it gets evaluated with the (global) plot data as the first and only argument. At  this point, the `mtcars` dataset is fed into your piping sequence. Note that code below `self$data` is the fortified data argument, so in your case, the piping sequence.

```
geom_text()$layer_data
#> <ggproto method>
#>   <Wrapper function>
#>     function(...) f(..., self = self)
#> 
#>   <Inner function (f)>
#>     function(self, plot_data) {
#>     if (is.waive(self$data)) {
#>       plot_data
#>     } else if (is.function(self$data)) {
#>       data <- self$data(plot_data)
#>       if (!is.data.frame(data)) {
#>         abort("Data function must return a data.frame")
#>       }
#>       data
#>     } else {
#>       self$data
#>     }
#>   }
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the extensive comment.
I agree that it opens the box of what's happening. But I'm missing where it makes explicit what dot refers to… is it obvious? I strongly suspect that this is the data inherited from the main ggplot() call, but if so I would really expect to see it documented (and incidentally whether the syntax is expected to be supported the future).

Comment: Does it help to see the piping bit as a function with the dot as it's first and only argument? You can essentially translate it to `function(x){summarise(group_by(x, cyl), hp = mean(hp))}` wherein the dot takes the place of `x`. The `x` is supplied in the `data <- self$data(plot_data)` line of the layer data method. You can see in the `?layer` docs that the `data` argument can take a function, which is what you're doing with the piping bit.

Comment: "the layer checks if the data is a function, and if it is, it gets evaluated with the (global) plot data as the first and only argument" that helps me understanding what's going on indeed. So is it the case that this dot is defined in the %+% operation of ggplot2 which adds layers to the ggplot() call?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the dot is pure magrittr and invokes the piping to be parameterised as a function(al sequence). ggplot2 then takes this function as uses it as it would any other. ggplot2 doesn't re-export the pipe `%>%` in contrast to many other tidyverse packages so I don't think there is any 'pipe-aware' functionality in ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I now understand that what I missed what this bit of geom_* doc: the argument `data` can be "a function will be called with a single argument, the plot data. The return value must be a data.frame, and will be used as the layer data. A function can be created from a formula (e.g. ~ head(.x, 10))." Got it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the `.` is accessing the same data as the global `mtcars`. The code below when run will produce the same graphic when you swap out the `.`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_text(
    aes(x=1, y=cyl, label=hp), 
    data=mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(hp=mean(hp)) 
  )
```

Comment: Yes, obviously… this I figured out but I'd like to know where the magic is coming from.
And whether magrittr or ggplot2 dot has precedence in the case I do sthg like

`
mtcars %>% {
ggplot(.) + 
  geom_text(
    aes(x=1, y=cyl, label=hp), 
    data=mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(hp=mean(hp)) 
  ) }
`